# Crash without warning xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, exc-bad-access

I am developing the application for over 6 month. 
After everithing was developed and tested, I put app aside for 2 weeks and now when I run it it start crashing without any warning:

[image]

Even if I hit Continue Execution over 20 times still nothing in log.

I have all exceptions break point and malloc_errer_break set.

App crash when I move from screen to screen (When I open 2 screen or when I close it).

Comment: Did you tried cleaning your project and reinstalling the app ?

Comment: breakpoint with all exceptions

Comment: clean Derived data folders

Comment: I did all that befour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess - you need to change a property to strong (from weak). Name of that problematic property you will find in the console after enabling check for zombies (press ⌘⇧< then check Enable Zombie Objects in Diagnostics/Memory Management)

Comment: I turned zombies object on and I see that I did some stupid mistake. I malloc : malloc(sizeof(int)*n) but recently I switch from int to long long and I forget to change malloc sizeof.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` happens when you use an object that no longer exists.

You could [check for Zombies during run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) to see if you use any of your object which doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This a very generic error, I suggest to review your code and try again and as Anc Ainu said the reason is of using an object thats no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend to set up Exception breakpoint to get place from
   which your app crashes.
   To make this breakpoint enabled go to breakpoint tab, then tap on plus button and choose 'Add Exception Breakpoint'.

[image]

[image]
 2. And yes, enabling NSZombies also could help
    you.